# Opera 11 and border-radius Issues

Tags: opera, jquery-cycle, css

This issue with border-radius and Opera 11.11 is driving me NUTS.

I have a span and an image set as background to that span.
I am applying a border-radius to the container that holds several such spans.

Like so:

```
#carousel { border-radius:15px;  margin:30px 0 0 0px; overflow:hidden; }
```

Forums tell me that border-radius is a supported property in Opera.
Also, the border-radius is applied to a block-level element and not an image.

Here's the demo:
http://rjwcollective.com/equinox/brochure/

Please provide pointers as to what I am missing here.

Rishi

Answer (score 0):

Your spans in the carousel are placed *over* the carousel, and they don't have any border-radius confgured. Any rounded border is below those spans.

THis works for me to see it in action (excuse the mess, just copy/pasting a working example from Dragonfly):

```
<div class="carousel_cont">
  <div id="carousel" style="position: relative; overflow-x: hidden; overflow-y: hidden; border-top-left-radius: 50px; border-top-right-radius: 50px; border-bottom-right-radius: 50px; border-bottom-left-radius: 50px">
    <span id="6" style="background-attachment: scroll; background-repeat: no-repeat; background-image: url(&quot;http://rjwcollective.com/equinox/brochure/images/assets/06pg.png&quot;); background-position: 0% 0%; background-size: auto; background-origin: padding-box; background-clip: border-box; background-color: transparent; width: 980px; height: 560px; top: 0px; z-index: 9; opacity: 1; display: block; left: 60px; border-top-right-radius: 100px; border-top-left-radius: 100px; border-bottom-right-radius: 100px; border-bottom-left-radius: 100px"></span>
  </div>
  <!-- end carousel -->
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks @Wrikken, however, the result I am expecting is more akin to the container (with border-radius applied) acting as a "mask" for the children <span>. This works in Firefox 4 and Webkit-based browsers as I expect, however, Opera is not liking something.

Comment: Ack, I don't know how it sits with the specification, but different behavior it is, maybe breaking the spec, of maybe not defined in the spec. (BTW: you _did_ forget to add a plain `border-radius:` in there, `#carousel` only has `-moz-border-radius:`, but that isn't the problem unfortunately, because adding them in with Dragonfly doesn't help).

Comment: strangely enough, there is an example that works in opera: http:www.equinox.com Wondering how they did it.

Comment: That's the old fashioned way: with images (carefully positioned http://www.equinox.com/resources/images/sprite-core.png).

Comment: I would have gone that route, had this not worked in all browsers.
It works in Webkit-based browsers, and firefox. Also, if I were to go the old-fashioned route, the slide-transition would reveal the rounded corner, no?

Comment: Just finished looking over their source. They have used a combination of methods including jquery.corner.js and DD_roundies. 

How were you saying that the image-based  solution would work? still clueless.

Comment: After utter and sheer frustration, I reverted to an image-based solution. Per @Wrikken 's comment (carefully positioned images)

When will border-radius behave in all browsers like it should?
Specifically its background clipping properties are so unpredictable and baffling. The w3c spec says that this behavior is "by design." Why?

Comment: It's the reason why W3c recommendations stay recommendations as long as they do before becoming a standard: all kinds of cases aren't covered, and independent implementations of a spec may differ in the fine details if not fully covered in said spec. Unfortunate, but the reality we have to deal with.

Comment: I see that there is a possible mention of a fix in [Opera 12.0 (Wahoo)](http://my.opera.com/desktopteam/blog/2011/09/02/new-wahoo-12-00-build-with-updated-core-and-speed-dial): _"CORE-25902 (border-radius doesn't clip replaced content)"_ I haven't checked it out myself, but it sure _sounds_ like the problem.